# Conditional Formatting Excel 2010 - Case Sensitive

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet `D6:JD36`. I want to conditionally format all the cells depending on their entered contents. Some of the cells are going to have "DH", while others are going to have "Dh", and I want the conditional formatting to be different colors for each.

I have tried:

```
=$D$6:$JD$36 Cell Value Equal To =EXACT($D$6:$JD$36,"DH")
=$D$6:$JD$36 Cell Value Equal To =EXACT($D$6:$JD$36,"Dh")
```

But when I enter EITHER "DH" or "Dh" into any cell it turns all of the cells in `D6:JD36` into the color of the CF at the top of the list, even if "STOP" is ticked.

Comment: What does this have to do with ColdFusion?

Answer (score 0):

In CELL D6
create conditional format, use `=EXACT(D6,"DH")`
create your format, then apply to whole range

Then repeat but use `=EXACT(D6,"Dh")` and change the format